# Creating a limited array with custom methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a helper object that will work the following way:
It is an array with a given number of rows, for example let's say it can hold only 3 rows.
It will have an insert method that inserts the a new entry at the first index, and pushes one index down all the rest (new entry is 0, 0 becomes 1, 1-->2 etc..)
and if the array is full to the max number of rows, the last entry drops out.

So I made it the following way:

```
function limArray(array, maxlength){

    this.arr = array;
    this.maxlength = maxlength;
    this.arr.length = maxlength;

    this.insertVal = function(value){ //insert new value and push down the rest

        for (var i=maxlength; i>=0; i--) { 
            this.arr[i] = this.arr[i-1]
        };
        this.arr[0] = value;
        this.arr.length = maxlength;
    };
}
```

My question is, if it's a smart way to make this?
Is it possible to create instance of the Array object itself and modify it to be limited etc..
Any critique / improvement suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could overwrite the `push` method:

```
function limArray(array, maxlength){
    var push_ = array.push,
        slice_ = [].slice;

    array.push = function() {
        var values = slice_.call(arguments, 0, maxlength - this.length);
        return push_.apply(this, values);
    }
    return array;
}
```

As [@alnorth29 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954042/creating-a-limited-array-with-custom-methods/6954433#6954433), you can use `unshift` to prepend a value. You can overwrite this as well:

```
function limArray(array, maxlength){
    // push like above
    var unshift_ = array.unshift;
    array.unshift = function() {
        unshift_.apply(this, arguments);
        this.length = this.length > maxlength ? maxlength : this.length;
        return this.length;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Of course you can also attach a new property with a more expressive name than `unshift`:

```
array.prepend = array.unshift;
```

If you extend an array instance like this, make sure you only traverse over its elements with a `for` loop, not with a `for...in` loop (you should always use `for` for arrays anyway). Another possibility is to define the property using ECMAScript 5's [`Object.defineProperty` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and set `enumerable` to `false`. But it is only supported in newer browsers.

There are other ways to add elements to an array, but I assume you are not going to use them .

Usage:

```
> var limited = limArray([], 3);
> limited.push(1,2,3,4);
  3
> limited
  [1, 2, 3]
> limited.push(5)
  3
> limited
  [1, 2, 3]

> var limited = limArray([], 3);
> limited.unshift(3, 4)
  2
> limited
  [3, 4]
> limited.unshift(1, 2)
  3
> limited
  [1, 2, 3]
```

**Update:**

I forgot, in case the array passed to the function already exceeds the maximum number of elements, you have to reduce the length:

```
function limArray(array, maxlength){
    array.length = array.length > maxlength ? maxlength : array.length;
    //...

    return array;
}
```

Comment: The op wanted to have a method that inserted values at the start of the array, not at the end.

Comment: @Felix Kling thanx for the detailed answer! why are you giving both the main and the inner function a `return` instead of saving the array in an inner variable like I did?

Comment: @IlyaD: In my case `limArray` is not a constructor. It just takes an array and makes it to a limited array by overriding methods. The method substitues return the same value as the original methods (`push` and `unshift`). I return `array` from `limArray` just for convenience. You could also do: `var arr = []; limArray(arr, 5);...`

Answer (score 1):

This looks fine to me, though you could use the [array's unshift method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to add values to the start of the array rather than manually updating all of them. This would make it more compact.

```
function limArray(array, maxlength){

    this.arr = array;
    this.maxlength = maxlength;
    this.arr.length = maxlength;

    this.insertVal = function(value){ //insert new value and push down the rest
        this.arr.unshift(value);
        this.arr.length = maxlength;
    };
}
```

As far as I know there's no built in way for defining the maximum length of an array.

Comment: You should only set `this.arr.length` to `maxlength` if the array's length exceeds `maxlength`.